# How to save a single data from session_data in ci_session

Tags: php, mysql, session, codeigniter-3

I need a single data like `first_name` to be save to another field using `ci_session`. How can I achieve this?

Here's `$session_data` that it's saving to `ci_session`. I need an specific data inside of it to be passed on to the log field.

> __ci_last_regenerate|i:1558420176;logged_in|b:1;profile|O:8:"stdClass":18:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:5:"email";s:17:"teacher@email.com";s:7:"role_id";s:1:"2";s:19:"tekteach_login_flag";s:1:"0";s:15:"date_registered";s:19:"0000-00-00 00:00:00";s:7:"deleted";s:1:"0";s:10:"first_name";s:4:"omar";s:9:"last_name";s:4:"isip";s:11:"middle_name";s:7:"chester";s:6:"gender";s:4:"Male";s:8:"birthday";s:10:"2019-05-10";s:6:"status";s:6:"Active";s:12:"grade_course";s:0:"";s:10:"created_on";N;s:10:"created_by";s:1:"0";s:11:"modified_on";N;s:11:"modified_by";s:1:"0";s:10:"deleted_by";s:1:"0";}

```
if ($this->_row_exists === FALSE)
{
    $insert_data = array(
        'id' => $session_id,
        'ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'timestamp' => time(),
        'data' => ($this->_platform === 'postgre' ? base64_encode($session_data) : $session_data),
        'log' => 1 //my own field
    );
```

Comment: Why are you saving all the session user data to the `$insert_data['data']`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the session item "first_name" to `$insert_data['log']` is quite simple. This answer assumes you're using CodeIgniter version > 3.0.0.

```
$insert_data = array(
    ...other items...
    'log' => $this->session->first_name;
);
```

If you want some other session data item simply change 'first_name' to the item desired. For example, the email data

```
'log' => $this->session->email;
```

Or, if you are absolutely positive that the item you want is present in session data you can also do this.

```
$insert_data = array(
    ...other items...
    'log' => $_SESSION['first_name'];
);
```

This is the least resource intensive and fastest way to get session data.
But beware, if `$_SESSION['first_name']` does not exist an error will be thrown. The first example will not throw an error but will return `NULL` instead.